# SQlite delete query not working despite no errors

Tags: python, sqlite

I have SQLlite table set up as follows:

```
name = List
tablename = namesOfTests
two columns = testNames and dueDate
```

Please see link - https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5c958b0c1ef9b54xjtktalx6

My code:

```
selectTest = "SampleSavedTest_Summ"
c1.execute("DELETE FROM namesOfTests WHERE testNames = ?;", (selectTest,))
```

The code runs with no errors, however, the database does not get updated. I would be grateful for some advice.

Please see comments below, @Parfait helped me fix it

Comment: Did you `commit()` just after or run with *autocommit* in connection?

Comment: Validate manually once if delete sql is framed correctly.. And check if applied sql is committed.

Comment: @Parfait Thank youuuuuuuu I had forgottten to do that. This fixes the issue. it also helped me with some other issues I was having with the main program